# Aspose slide include svg into ppt slide

Tags: aspose, aspose-slides

Does Aspose slide include svg into ppt slide? Is there way using slide api to do this? Any snippet would be good for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to please try using following sample code on your end using latest Aspose.slides for .NET 17.12.

```
string dataDir = RunExamples.GetDataDir_PresentationProperties();
using (var pres = new Presentation())
{
    var svgContent = File.ReadAllText(svgPath);
    var emfImage = p.Images.AddFromSvg(svgContent);
    pres.Slides[0].Shapes.AddPictureFrame(ShapeType.Rectangle, 0, 0, emfImage.Width, emfImage.Height, emfImage);
    pres.Save(outPptxPath, SaveFormat.Pptx);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have observed your requirements and like to share that feature of adding SVG inside slide has been included in MS PowerPoint 2016. I regret to share that at present the requested support is unavailable in Aspose.Slides and an issue with ID **SLIDESNET-39110** has been added to provide the requested support. This thread has been linked with the issue so that we may share notification with you once support will be available.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Many Thanks,

Comment: @ SO19, Please refer to my below response for sample code. The issue has been fixed since Aspose.Slides for .NET 17.12.